# How can I tell Real Art from Fake Art from Jolly Redd?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Redd has appeared on my island, selling art on his sketchy boat. If I know anything about this tricky Kitsune, he's trying to sell me fake stuff again.

How can I tell which art is real vs fake?

Answer (score 1):

This [article](http://www.nintendolife.com/guides/animal-crossing-new-horizons-redd-how-to-spot-fake-paintings-and-statues-and-unlock-crazy-redd) lists all the paintings and sculptures and what to look for to see if they’re fake or not.
Usually, it’s a variation of the real piece (different color, missing person/object etc), so if you know the paintings, it could be fun to first try to guess by yourself if it’s fake or not (and then double checking of course before buying :) ).
To check by yourself, you'll have to use the option "Take a closer look" as the boat's lightning is (on purpose, wily Redd) almost inexistent..